# cada vez que va a dar la segunda vuelta del ciclo se me agregran mas valores al calcular el promedio

Tags: array, c

Cada vez que da la segunda vuelta al calcular el promedio se me suman más valores ejemplo: si pongo 80+50+45 tendría que dar ya hecho toda la operación 58 pero en la segunda vuelta del ciclo si pongo los mismos se me agregan más valores.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int notas[3], may = 0, i;
  char opcion[3];
  float prom = 0, suma = 0;
  char nombre[3][20], materia[3][20];
  fflush(stdin);
  do {
    printf("Ingrese el nombre del alumno\n");
    scanf("%s", nombre);
    printf("Ingrese la materia del estudiante\n");
    scanf("%s", materia);
    fflush(stdin);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

      printf("Ingrese la nota del estudiante\n");
      printf("notas %d:", i + 1);
      fflush(stdin);
      scanf("%d", & notas[i]);
      suma += notas[i];
    }
    prom = suma / 3;
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("El promedio de %s es: %.1f\n\n", nombre, prom);

    if (prom < 70) {

      printf("------El estudiante %s Reprobo-----\n\n", nombre);
    } else {
      printf("------El estudiante %s Aprobo--------\n\n", nombre);
    }

    printf("Desea calcular otras notas? ¿(si/no)?\n");
    scanf("%s", opcion);

  } while (opcion[0] == 'S' || opcion[0] == 's');
  return 0;
}
```

este de acá es el código

Comment: Tendrías que inicializar la variable suma al inicio del bloque `while`, porque, si no, mantiene los resultados anteriores...

Comment: Lo haré bro ahora mismo

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que la variable suma mantiene los acumulados de los estudiantes previos, en cada iteración, cuando el usuario confirma que quiere cargar otro alumno, reiniciar suma en el valor 0 haciendo:

```
suma = 0;
```

Tu código quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int notas[3], may = 0, i;
  char opcion[3];
  float prom = 0, suma = 0;
  char nombre[3][20], materia[3][20];
  fflush(stdin);
  do {
    printf("Ingrese el nombre del alumno\n");
    scanf("%s", nombre);
    printf("Ingrese la materia del estudiante\n");
    scanf("%s", materia);
    fflush(stdin);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

      printf("Ingrese la nota del estudiante\n");
      printf("notas %d:", i + 1);
      fflush(stdin);
      scanf("%d", & notas[i]);
      suma += notas[i];
    }
    prom = suma / 3;
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("El promedio de %s es: %.1f\n\n", nombre, prom);

    if (prom < 70) {

      printf("------El estudiante %s Reprobo-----\n\n", nombre);
    } else {
      printf("------El estudiante %s Aprobo--------\n\n", nombre);
    }

    printf("Desea calcular otras notas? ¿(si/no)?\n");
    scanf("%s", opcion);
    suma=0; /* <------------------------ ESTA ES LA LINEA A AGREGAR --------- */
  } while (opcion[0] == 'S' || opcion[0] == 's');
  return 0;
}
```